# Resizing an image from the source and setting the upload path with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation, codeigniter-2

I'm building an image gallery with Codeigniter everything is going good so far, but I had a quick question about image resizing.

Basically I upload the source image, and make create an id then store it in that path /uploads/$id/source.jpg. Then I try to create two new images of the source image, a thumbnail and a medium image with a watermark.

When using Codeigniter's Image Manipulation Class can you set a file name and a upload path? And when you give it the source image does it modify the source image or does it make a copy?

```
public function generateThumnail($source, $screenid) {
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = "$source";
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;

        //Not sure how I set the upload path and file name.
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        //TODO: Code to be added later
        $this->image_lib->clear();
}
```

The upload path and the file name aren't include because I'm not sure how to add them. Is there any way to add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify an upload path but by using the File Uploading Class, not the Image Manipulation Class.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '100';
$config['max_width'] = '1024';
$config['max_height'] = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

CodeIgniter will create a copy of the image if you tell it to.

> **Creating a Copy**
>
> The resizing function will create a copy of the image file (and
>   preserve the original) if you set a path and/or a new filename using
>   this preference:

```
$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';
```

> Notes regarding this preference:
>
> - If only the new image name is specified it will be placed in the same folder as the original
> - If only the path is specified, the new image will be placed in the destination with the same name as the original.
> - If both the path and image name are specified it will placed in its own destination and given the new name.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html